# When Insert New Record, Trigger for Generate That New Record in XML Automatically

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica, bigdata

Hello Informatica Gurus,

I'm brand new to Informatica, the only training I have is fiddling around with the it for couple days trying to figure this out, so there is a lot I don't know. I have unique case where my company using AS400 (IBM DB2) and want every time their AS400 software insert a new record, the Informatica can generate new XML based on that new record.

Please let me know if this is possible or not.

Best regards, 
Yanitra

Comment: You need to advise on how frequently you want this information extracted, daily, hourly, realtime? If its realtime then you need to configure power exchange. In powercenter, parsing to xml is no big feat

Comment: Sure, that's feasible. Set up a mapping that reads data and generates an XML. Add a variable to hold latest timestamp/id and with each run fetch all newer rows. Only catch is that XML Generator will create a row even if no data will come from input, so you'd need to add a filter that lets only non empty xml rows pass. Then create a workflow and schedule it according to your needs. Give it a try, get back here if you come across issues.

Comment: @Maciejg What if the table have 26 million rows? (yeah, because this is big company that still stuck with AS400 software)

Comment: I'm not keen on AS400, but if you can do a delta on some timestamp / key which is indexed, the size mentioned should not be a problem. The question is if you can come up with an effective query that runs fast and returns new rows since your last timestamp.

Comment: @Maciejg thanks for your response. I already try and its work (thanks a lot), but I have another question. If I want use CDC table, it is still need compare with another table or can generate XML automatically?

Comment: Not sure I understand. It should be possible to avoid any comparison. Perhaps if you'd share some more details or a screenshot, I'd be able to tell more.

Comment: There should be no comparison needed.